# How to get back stock recovery when wrongly flashed twrp recovery?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, boot-loop, fastboot

I have Videocon Delite 21 V50MB phone running Android 6.0. The stock recovery was not working well(showing "No command" always) so I decided to flash TWRP recovery via adb and fastboot. My phone model was not listed in the TWRP website so I downloaded a random recovery.img file and flashed after bootloader unlocking using commands:

```
fastboot oem unlock

fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

It showed completed on CMD but when I rebooted my phone its getting the videocon logo disappearing and again appearing(bootloop). I cannot run on the stock recovery either. I am also not getting any stock rom for my phone model on the internet. Please help me what to do next?

Comment: Well you do need the original image - if you haven't backed that up then you need a factory image, and if that doesn't exist either then you're stuck.

Comment: I have not backed it up but still I have another smartphone of same model. So can you please tell me how to backup recovery.img file from that 2nd same model phone without rooting and unlocking bootloader? That's my friends phone so I want the safest way to backup without doing any harm to his phone. @andy yan

Comment: "without rooting and unlocking bootloader" - not one I know of. The `dd` command is the common way of doing partition backup, but unfortunately that requires root.